# Как получить Unicode код числа?

Tags: c#, unicode, числа

Согласно вот этой таблице:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть строка "\u0000\u0001\u0002\u0003" и combobox со string "0", "1", "2" .. "9". Нужно изменить в строке один символ (например первый)

`"\u0000" + val + "\u0002\u0003"`

так чтобы в конце было число из combobox

val = "\u000{{x}}"

Если клеить строку "\u000" + "3" то способ записи литерала не работает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Столбец Decimal на вашей картинке видите?

```
char a = (char)3;
char b = '\u0003';
Console.WriteLine(a == b); // True
```

Comment: добавил здесь, ответ решил проблему

Answer (score 0):

```
var number = 3;
Console.WriteLine(number.ToString("X4"));
```

Выведет "0003"